# Merge [symfony2-easyadmin] into [easyadmin]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just discovered there is a [easyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/easyadmin) and a [symfony2-easyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin) tag. Since EasyAdmin is based on Symfony the latter doesn't make sense in the first place and secondly, we've got multiple `symfony*` tags. A question about EasyAdmin and a specific Symfony version can be tagged with both `easyadmin` and `symfony*`.

Some of the [symfony2-easyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin) questions are also tagged with:

- [`easyadmin3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin+easyadmin3)
- [`symfony-3.1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin+symfony-3.1) (or [with keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsymfony2-easyadmin%5D+Symfony+3.1))
- [`symfony-3.2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin+symfony-3.2) (or [with keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsymfony2-easyadmin%5D+Symfony+3.2))
- [`symfony-3.3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin+symfony-3.3)
- [`symfony-3.4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin+symfony-3.4) (or [with keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsymfony2-easyadmin%5D+Symfony+3.4))
- [`symfony4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-easyadmin+symfony4)  (or [with keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsymfony2-easyadmin%5D+-%5Bsymfony4%5D+Symfony+4))

EasyAdmin 3 requires Symfony 4.4 and the other tags are incompatible for obvious reasons.

Let's merge these two tags. Their excerpt and description are already identical.

Comment: What about naming the new tag `[symfony-easyadmin]`? You proposed similar actions in your other question: [Consistency of Symfony Component tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/consistency-of-symfony-component-tags)

Comment: EasyAdmin is not a Symfony Component. We aren't gonna change all tags of [these projects](https://symfony.com/projects), are we? ;)

Comment: This request is similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410566/merge-symfony-sonata-into-sonata.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this proposal. This change would make a lot of sense to me.