# Merge [symfony-sonata] into [sonata]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[sonata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sonata) is a project based on Symfony, so it makes no sense to have a [symfony-sonata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-sonata) tag. Questions about the Sonata Project can be tagged with [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) (or [symfony4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony4) or [symfony5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony5)).

The descriptions/excerpt of both tags are outdated, I'll update them when they're merged.

See [Merge [symfony2-easyadmin] with [easyadmin]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410543/merge-symfony2-easyadmin-with-easyadmin)  for a similar request.