# Consistency of Symfony Component tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

While looking at Symfony Component related tags (see [Merge [symfony-components] with [symfony]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410588/merge-symfony-components-with-symfony)), I've seen some inconsistency in the naming of those tags. Let's stick to the official naming of the [Components](https://symfony.com/components) <sup>1</sup>.

Here's what should be renamed:

- [domcrawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domcrawler) -> [symfony-domcrawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-domcrawler)
- [symfony-config-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-config-component) -> [symfony-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-config)
- [symfony-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-forms) -> [symfony-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-form)
- [options-resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options-resolver) -> [symfony-options-resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-options-resolver)
- [simple-phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simple-phpunit) -> [symfony-phpunit-bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-phpunit-bridge) <sup>2</sup>
- [symfony-workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-workflows) -> [symfony-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-workflow)
- [symfony-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-kernel) -> [symfony-http-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-http-kernel)

These tags could be merged <sup>3</sup>:

- [symfony2-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-forms) into [symfony-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-form)
- [symfony2-voter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2-voter) into [symfony-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-security)

The components are CamelCase, but tags are kebab-case (HttpClient: [symfony-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-http-client), DependencyInjection: [symfony-dependency-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-dependency-injection)), but not all (EventDispatcher: [symfony-eventdispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-eventdispatcher). I've ignored that for now. Should I mention them as well?

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F_Pgz8wUCpdT-06sIYpzg_1LuEqHhkGt8FfRO6Ku4G8/edit?usp=sharing) for a list of components with their tags.

<sup>2</sup> `simple-phpunit` sounds like an alternative to/extension of phpunit itself, but it is a command line tool from the Symfony PHPUnit Bridge: https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/5.3/bin/simple-phpunit.php. I added 'bridge' in the tag name to make it clear it's not a component.

<sup>3</sup> [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2) is an [alias](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony) of [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony), so their component-based tags should follow the same routine.